# Is Geometry subjective or is it objective?

Tags: geometry

As far as I'm concerned geometry is not subjective but a few of my peers thing that it is and i would like to know as to what the mathematics community thinks of this statement. I've heard of a thing called subjective Geometry but i have no clue as to what it is and its purpose.

Comment: I'm guessing that the votes to close are because this is not strictly a mathematics question but a philosophy question.

Comment: ask immanuel kant

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you mean. However, when one thinks of geometry as a branch of physics (and mathematics) the question of what is the geometry of physical space is an important one. However, mathematics also looks at geometry from an axiomatic point of view in which case one can choose to study any of the different kinds of geometry and there is no particular reason to choose one type of geometry over the other from some points of view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I answered on StackOverflow:

Subjective geometry a fancy term for optical illusions. So the geometry itself is solid and completely objective in a physical sense. But like subjective things, perceptions of it differ between observers.

[source](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0270025580900457)